# Searching Different Tables In Same Query

Tags: php, sql

I have figured out how to search the same table for different attributes in that table for a search function. However, the one problem I am having is that I cannot figure out how to search two or more different tables in the same query.

I have attached my query code below; it just says that the query is wrong:

```
    $search= $_POST['searchfun'];

    // Connect database server
    $connection = sqlsrv_connect( $hostName, $connectionInfo )
        or die("ERROR: selecting database server failed");

    //table to store data   
    $userTable = "TRIP";

    // prepare SQL query
    $query = "(
                SELECT * 
                FROM TRIP 
                WHERE DestinationLocation LIKE '%$search%'
                    OR DepartureLocation LIKE '%$search%'
                    OR DepartureTime LIKE '%$search%'
                    OR DestinationTime LIKE '%$search%'
                    OR Distance LIKE '%$search%'
                    OR Cost LIKE '%$search%'
                    OR LicensePlate LIKE '%$search%'
                )
                UNION (
                SELECT * 
                FROM USERS 
                WHERE StudentId LIKE '%$search%'
                    OR FullName LIKE '%$search%'
                    OR SchoolEmail LIKE '%$search%'
                    OR Birthday LIKE '%$search%'
                    OR Username LIKE '%$search%'
                    OR Password LIKE '%$search%'
                    OR Type LIKE '%$search%'
                )";
```

Comment: Why not join those table or you meant different db?

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя They are separate tables in the same database

Comment: I only see one `TRIP` table why dont use `OR` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza what do you mean only one TRIP table and to use OR?

Answer (score 0):

```
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM TRIP 
    WHERE DestinationLocation LIKE '%$search%'
       OR DepartureTime LIKE '%$search%'
       OR Distance LIKE '%$search%'
       OR Cost LIKE '%$search%'
       OR LicensePlate LIKE '%$search%'
       OR SchoolEmail LIKE '%$search%'
   )
   UNION
   (SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE SchoolEmail LIKE '%$search%')
```

Comment: For some reason, it still says that the query is wrong.

Comment: Yes never say something was wrong, show us the error. You need to have same number of columns on each union select otherwise wont work

Comment: I updated my code in the original question. Do you think you could help me determine if there are still issues?

Comment: show us the `CREATE TABLE` for each table. As I say you are using `SELECT *` i seriuosly doubt those tables have same structure. Is like you try to join orange and eggs.

Comment: Oh okay I understand now, yeah the tables have different structures for sure. Is there a way that I can name each individual column in the different tables (i.e.- SELECT Cost, Distance, LicensePlate, ... FROM ...)?

Comment: yes, instead of use `*` write each field name you need, just make sure every one have same type.